# Set Text Font Size and Vertical Center of Text UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, bounds

I have implemented the following class to center my text in my `UITextView`.

```
class VerticallyCenteredTextView: UITextView {
override var contentSize: CGSize {
    didSet {
        var topCorrection = (bounds.size.height - contentSize.height * zoomScale) / 2.0
        topCorrection = max(0, topCorrection)
        contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topCorrection, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
} 
}
```

I have also implemented the following method, which adjusts the size of the font according to the amount of space in the `UITextView` :

```
func updateTextFont(textView : UITextView, minSize : CGFloat, maxSize : CGFloat) {
if (textView.text.isEmpty || CGSizeEqualToSize(textView.bounds.size, CGSizeZero)) {
    return;
}

let textViewSize = textView.frame.size;
let fixedWidth = textViewSize.width;
let expectSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)));

var expectFont = textView.font;
if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {
    while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > textViewSize.height && (textView.font!.pointSize > CGFloat(minSize))) {
        expectFont = textView.font!.fontWithSize(textView.font!.pointSize - 1)
        textView.font = expectFont
    }
}
else {
    while (textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < textViewSize.height && (textView.font!.pointSize < CGFloat(maxSize))) {
        expectFont = textView.font;
        textView.font = textView.font!.fontWithSize(textView.font!.pointSize + 1)
    }
    textView.font = expectFont;
}
}
```

Now this method works very well with a normal `UITextView`, however it does not work at all with my `VerticallyCenteredTextView` because of the edge insets which are applied when the `VerticallyCenteredTextView` is initialised, before the `updateTextFont` function can ever be called. Is there a way I could combine these two code snippets to obtain a `UITextView` which adjusts the text font based on the amount of space available AND centers the text vertically in the `UITextView`?

Comment: Why not put your `contentSize`'s `didSet` implementation into its own method and call it at the end of `updateTextFont()`?

Comment: Would I access the 'bounds', 'contentSize' and 'zoomscale' using 'mytextView.zoomscale' for example?